# Opengrok can't ignore patterns

Tags: opengrok

Opengrok is able to provide searching already, but it failed to ignore files, even `IGNORE_PATTERNS` is defined.

```
export IGNORE_PATTERNS="-i f:*.o -i f:*.out -i f:*.so -i f:*.class -i f:*.swp -i f:*.cache -i f:*.gitignore -i f:*.gitmodules -i f:*.project -i f:*.classpath -i f:*.log.* -i f:*.jar -i d:.git -i d:.settings -i d:target -i d:bin -i d:build -i d:gen -i d:test-output"
```

I already tried to remove `data/` dir, and re-index, still can't ignore specified pattern.

The searching result still show items from `*.log` and `*.class` files.

Any idea?

---

### @Update - solution

I am using **opengrok-1.1-rc21**, actually simply change env name to `OPENGROK_IGNORE_PATTERNS` solved the issue.

Thanks to `@MarceloÁviladeOliveira`'s comment in below answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure you can use the "f:" and "d:" to choose between files and directories (see update below) but you could try to use a "/" before the directories names.

So you could, for example, try to replace:

```
f:*.classpath => *.classpath
d:.git        => */.git/*
```

I was able to ignore all .test files and the test-dir directory executing:

```
OPENGROK_CONFIGURATION=opengrok.conf OpenGrok index
```

With a opengrok.conf file with this:

```
...
IGNORE_PATTERNS="-i *.test -i */test-dir/*"
```

**UPDATE**

Actually the "f:" and "d:" modifiers can be used... the issue was the "IGNORE_PATTERNS" variable which was changed to "OPENGROK_IGNORE_PATTERNS" in OpenGrok v1.1.

See more info [here](https://github.com/oracle/opengrok/issues/1823).

Comment: I tried that, still not working, can you pass here a `$IGNORE_PATTERNS` example ?

Comment: I just added more info.

Comment: `OPENGROK_IGNORE_PATTERNS` is the name of the environment variable in the current version of `OpenGrok` script.

Comment: @CFraire Yep, that is the actual reason !

Comment: @MarceloÁviladeOliveira I am using `opengrok-1.1-rc21`, actually simply change env name to `OPENGROK_IGNORE_PATTERNS` solved the issue. `d:` and `f:` are valid format, and `f:` is optional, I think `d:` is more neat thatn `*/xxx/*`, right?